# python: How to add 3rd and more x-axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

I have to use 3 x-axis (scaled):

```
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax2 = ax1.twiny()
ax3 = ax1.twiny()
```

Is a way to draw ax2 and ax3 as separated lines, like it is possible to y-axis.
tired to play with .set_position, but looks like it is different

[image]

Comment: your question does not clarify

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
ax3.spines['top'].set_position(('axes', 1.1))
```

[image]